# How to convert a for loop in list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have this for loop

```
def isPrime(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        return True
```

I tried to rewrite it with list comprehension following the general syntax of list comprehension, but I always get an error.
eventually it has to print a list of prime numbers with this command:

```
print([x for x in range(2, 100) if isPrime(x)])
```

Comment: You do not seem to rewrite the loop in `isPrime`, but to define a list comprehension *over* the `isPrime` function.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking - what error do you get? You said you tried to re-write it, but you seem to be calling the function, not re-writing it. What's the error and what do you want us to do?

Comment: in the function isPrime I'd like to rewrite the for loop in a list comprehension.

Comment: What error are you getting? Also your function `isPrime` is wrong. You should `return True` **after** the `for` loop ends.

Comment: The aim of this function is the return a list of prime numbers. When I rewrite the function in a list comprehension I receive a simple list of integer from 3 untill 99.

Comment: Why do you want to change the for loop to a list comprehension - at the moment it returns a single value, `True` or `False`, not a list.  Are you actually asking how to write a single list comprehension to give some prime numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you have been thinking of something like this?

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n < 2: return None
    factors = [ i for i in range(2, n) if n%i == 0 ]
    return True if not factors else False

print( [ i for i in range(1, 100) if isPrime(i) ] )
#PRINTS:
[2,  3,  5,  7,  11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 
 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Comment: Great.Thank you!
and as Keyur Potdar mentionned my return True statement was misplaced.